# Importing into existing table with bulk insert SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I already have an existing table with millions of rows.  An external text file (tab delimited) needs to be able to an existing table.  After both sets of data are in the same table I will normalize.  My existing table has the same table structure as the one I'm importing.  If i do something like

```
BULK INSERT TableName
        FROM 'C:\SomeDirectory\my table.txt'
            WITH
    (
                FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
                ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
    )
GO
```

Will this append, or replace the existing data?

Comment: Have you tried [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx)?  I think it's pretty clear that it's importing into the table, i.e., adding to the end of the existing data.

Comment: so  much of that didn't apply to my situation (all the options for bulk insert) i felt it safer to ask experts first.

Comment: Understood.  The documentation can be difficult to wade through.  If you scroll down far enough, you'll typically find a section called `remarks` which provides helpful general clarifications.

Comment: thanks, i'll have to start that.  the documentation is often overwhelming for a naive learner, i wholeheartedly agree.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appends. If you want to replace, TRUNCATE or DELETE first.